# When using paypal smart button on subscruiption page and on order page its showing error " Do not pass both createSubscription and createOrder"

Tags: reactjs, paypal-subscriptions

When using PayPal smart button on subscription page and on order page its showing error " Object { err: "Do not pass both create Subscription and createOrder\nE@https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&components.0=buttons&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVRrMmdPc2VnTG90Q1U1YmNFMXJHaXR2eGlzUEVNYTRMRklYNUwwX2pzM0tjVFZjWmlSNU5BRG9ubFhVN3JnNmJicms2cHJmZVNkdHIxZXomdmF1bHQ9dHJ1ZSIsInN0YWdlSG9zdCI6bnVsbCwiYXBpU3RhZ2VIb3N0IjpudWxsfQ&clientID=ATk2gOsegLotCU5bcE1rGitvxisPEMa4LFIX5L0_js3KcTVcZiR5NADonlXU7rg6bbrk6prfeSdtr1ez&sessionID=81e79b9dc1_mti6ndy6ndi&buttonSessionID=cdf48d395b_mtm6mdq6mdg&env=sandbox&fundingEligibility=eyJwYXlwYWwiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOnRydWV9LCJ2ZW5tbyI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9LCJpdGF1Ijp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZX0sImNyZWRpdCI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9LCJzZXBhIjp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZX0sImlkZWFsIjp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZX0sImJhbmNvbnRhY3QiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOmZhbHNlfSwiZ2lyb3BheSI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9LCJlcHMiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOmZhbHNlfSw…", timestamp: "1568293452093", referer: "www.sandbox.paypal.com", uid: "81e79b9dc1_mti6ndy6ndi", env: "sandbox" }"

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#4-create-a-subscription

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
```

script.src = "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=ATk2gOsegLotCU5bcE1rGitvxisPEMa4LFIX5L0_js3KcTVcZiR5NADonlXU7rg6bbrk6prfeSdtr1ez&vault=true";
script.async = true;

document.body.appendChild(script);

```
createSubscription =  {(data:any, actions:any) => {
  return actions.subscription.create({
    'plan_id': 'P-74Y99789642891518ETPKJAY'
  });
}}





    onApprove={(data:any, actions:any)=> {

        alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID);
    }
}

  />
```

Its showing error it should be in success

Comment: This is really hard to read. Could you format your question in such a way to be more readable?

Comment: I am trying to use paypal smart button for subscription.But its not working for me.
Using this documentation ===>https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#4-create-a-subscription

Comment: Any solutions to this? @NetsetDev